# Powerseries of $\frac 1 {1-x}$ around $a \in \mathbb R \backslash \{0\}$.

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

Can someone help me finding a power series around $a \in \mathbb R \backslash \{0\}$ which converges to $\frac 1 {1-x}$ for $|x-a| < R$ and some $R > 0$
 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Around $0$,
$$\frac1{1-x}=1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+\ldots$$
absolutely convergent if $|x| <1$.

You can use this, let $x=y+a$, then
$$\frac1{1-x}=\frac1{1-(y+a)}=\frac1{(1-a)-y} = \frac1{1-a}\cdot\frac1{1-\frac y{1-a}} . $$

So, use the above for $z:=\frac y{1-a}\ $ for $a\ne 1$. We have a convergent powerseries for $|z|<1$, i.e.\ $|y|<|1-a|=:R$.

Comment: Yes. Thanks. I get $$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty (1-a)^{-n-1}(x-a)^n$$ for $x \in (a-1,a+1)$

Comment: Yes, but rather $x\in (1,2a-1)$ in case $a>1$..